# Kommasetzung: "Der fünfte Teil der Reihe(,) Skyrim(,) ..."

Tags: grammar, punctuation, comma, apposition

Ich bin beim Schreiben über folgenden Satz gestolpert:

> Der fünfte Teil der Elder Scrolls-Reihe, *Skyrim*, ist ...

Den Namen "Skyrim" habe ich intuitiv durch Kommata abgegrenzt. Ich bin mir nicht näher, aber der Name des Spiels scheint mir eine nähere Beschreibung des vorangegangenen Hauptsatzes, insofern wäre der Name als eingeschobener Hauptsatz zu sehen? (Kommaregeln sind nicht meine Stärke, gab es nicht eine Regel, nach der das Komma nur dann gesetzt werden muss, wenn der eingeschobene Nebensatz **nicht** notwendigerweise zur näheren Bestimmung des Substantives benötigt wird?) Allerdings lese ich häufig solche Konstrukte, bei denen keine Kommata verwendet werden, also:

> Der fünfte Teil der Elder Scrolls-Reihe *Skyrim* ist ...

Gibt es hierzu eine Regel? Oder geht beides (und wenn ja, welche liest sich seriöser)?

Comment: Das Komma zur Unterscheidung von erläuternden und bestimmenden Relativsätzen ist eine rein englische Institution. Im Deutschen trägt der Relativsatz immer ein Komma. Es gibt eine entprechende deutsche Regel für mehrfache attributive Adjektive, aber auch die ist hier nicht relevant, da es sich um Appositionen (mehrere Nominalphrasen) handelt.

Comment: Jetzt müßte man wissen, ob _Skyrim_ der Titel nur des fünften Teils ist, oder ob die ganze Reihe so heißt, denn darauf kommt es an. In jedem Fall fehlt aber ein Bindestrich: Elder-Scrolls-Reihe.

Comment: @chirlu Skyrim ist der Titel des fünften Teiles. Die Antwort von Ralph dürfte also richtig sein. Ohne Bindestrich ist aber schon richtig so, *Elder Scrolls* ist ein Eigenname, der so geschrieben wird ...
@ Kilian Dann war das wohl eine Erinnerung an den Englisch-Unterricht ... kommt auch vor ^^'

Comment: Nee, nee, Eigenname hin oder her, es wird durchgekoppelt. Ist auch auf Straßenschildern zu besichtigen: _Angela-Merkel-Straße_ u.ä. (Jedenfalls meistens, denn auch Verwaltungen und Schilderproduzenten stehen nicht selten mit der Rechtschreibung auf Kriegsfuß.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Der fünfte Teil der Elder-Scrolls-Reihe hat den Namen Skyrim. Damit beschreibt Skyrim die vorangegangene Klausel näher und wird, wie der OP es intuitiv gemacht hat, mit Kommata abgetrennt.

Korrekt ist also:

> Der fünfte Teil der Elder-Scrolls-Reihe, Skyrim, ist ...

In der Formulierung

> Der fünfte Teil der Elder-Scroll-Reihe Skyrim ist ...

beschreibt *Skyrim* die ganze Elder-Scrolls-Reihe näher, und das wäre nur richtig, wenn alle fünf Teile zusammen diesen Namen hätten.

Skyrim im ersten Fall ist eine [weite Apposition, welche immer zwischen zwei Kommata oder Komma und Punkt steht](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apposition). Klarer ersichtlich ist es in der Umkehrung:

> Skyrim, der fünfte Teil der Elder-Scrolls-Reihe, ist ...

Im zweiten Fall handelt es sich um eine enge Apposition, welche keine Kommata verwendet. Dabei beschreibt das zweite Nomen direkt das vorangegangene.